# How to add fragment inside a fragment of ViewPager with same id where each fragment added in view pager is same?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I am trying to add a fragment inside another fragment which is added in view pager. All fragment inside view pager are same. I am just viewing them with swipe. On button click, i add a fragment inside our main fragment by using add fragment. On doing this, this new fragment is being added to last fragment of view pager instead of current one. 
Reason which seems to me is when we look for fragment, we still have last fragment active and that fragment adds this new fragment on top of it.

Everything works fine for first

```
public void onAddFragmentClick(View view) {
    if (!isInfoShown) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        fragment = new MainFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment, "detail fragment");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        isInfoShown = true;
    } else {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        isInfoShown = false;
    }
}
```

Main Fragment which is added in viewpager is

```
<RelativeLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.wedm.wedme.ui.fragment.PictureScreenFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: For nested fragments you should use the child fragment manager of the fragment where you want to add fragments. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks man. You saved my day. Please add this in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For nested fragments you should use the child fragment manager of the fragment where you want to add fragments. Hope this helps.